# how to retrieve function variable in ajax done function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this js function:

```js
$('.editable').change(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var el_text = this.lastElementChild;
    var action = this.action;
    var method = this.method;
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: method,
        data: data,
    }).done(function (resp) {

        // alert('has changed!');
    });
});
```

How can I retrieve `el_text` inside **done()** which appears here to be undefined?

Comment: your ajax callback is in the scope of your `editable.change` callback, you should be able to access it as your code is...?

Comment: how are you trying to access it? Using `el_text` or using `this.lastElementChild` inside the `.done()` method?

Comment: It is readable, so it means that `this.lastElementChild` was undefined in the first place

Comment: `el_text` should be available in the above callback. It's probably, rather, that el_text is undefined already.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make var el_text a public variable or send the data of var el_text to the server and send it back again with the resp

```js
var el_text = "";
$('.editable').change(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    el_text = this.lastElementChild;
    var action = this.action;
    var method = this.method;
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: method,
        data: data,
    }).done(function (resp) {

        // alert('has changed!');
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd like to understang why your answer has been downvoted. Is there any reason?

Comment: @EmilioConte I dont know. People usually dont explain why they downvote but if I were you. I would look at the other answer here and the comments. It might further help you.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but likely because there's no reason to over engineer this.  In OPs original code *as provided*, `el_text` **is already available** in the $.ajax .done() "callback".  If OP was not getting this, then their code was not as presented in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this because the scope of the done callback
   function consider this within its own scope so to get that variable
   you can simply reference this in variable that outside ajax

```
var objectElement = this;
```

then after done callback you can call it like this.

```
$.ajax({
       url: action,
       type: method,
       data: data,
}).done(function (resp) {
     $(objectElement).lastElementChild;     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.editable').change(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var el_text = this.lastElementChild;
    var action = this.action;
    var method = this.method;
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    // $.ajax({
    //     url: action,
    //     type: method,
    //     data: data,
    // }).done(function (resp) {
    //     // when this is called, el text could be something else as the change event could fire multiple times by differnt element.
    // });

    (function(el_text){
        // now el_text in here is locked in this function scope, 
        // won't be affected by the parent scope
        $.ajax({ 
            url: action,
            type: method,
            data: data,
        }).done(function (resp) {
            // now you can do something with el_text here
        });
    })(el_text);
});
```

check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake

Comment: What's the meaning of ```(el_text);``` alone at the end?

Comment: I created a function (with no name) then immediately called it. this way the el_text value gets copied into the inner function scope.